# Navigation toggle class on only clicked item not all

Tags: html, jquery

I have a a navigation with a sub navigation which is hidden by default, and I want to show the sub nav for each item on click, but currently on click it shows the subnav for all items at once since the click is toggling a class. How can I only toggle the subnav of the clicked item?

**HTML**

```
<nav class="st-menu" id="menu-4a">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Guidance Manual</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Resource Directory</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Plan Review Resources</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pilot Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Proprietary Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Additional Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Stormwater 101</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Regulations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Stormwater Billing & Retrofits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Green City, Clean Waters</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a><div class="toggle-arrow"><img src="/assets/images/chevron-up-solid.svg"/></div>
            <ul class="reg-subnav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Development Review Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
});
```

Comment: `$(".reg-subnav")` is a global selector.  You need to use a contextual selector that reduces the scope to only find the element related to the one that was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".toggle-arrow").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find(".reg-subnav").toggleClass('open-sub');
});
```

Both the arrow and the element you want to toggle, belong to an `<li>`.  You can find the closest parent li that owns both of them, then find the element you want to toggle.

Comment: Is there a way I can make that if the user toggle open a subnav while one is already open that it closes the open one, thus only allowing one open at a time?

Comment: Yes, you would have to find other navs that have the open-sub class on them that are not related to the one that was clicked, and remove the class from them.